# How to mix persistent and transient state of a domain object?

Tags: hibernate, object, persistence

I'm looking for a pattern/method do cleanly solve the following problem :

In a on-screen display application (various information is displayed on LCD screens in public places), I have **Hibernate persistent POJOs**, that can be created and updated in the administration part of my app.

In the "display" part, which is read-only, I use these objects. They must be always up-to-date with the persisted state, but they also have a transient state (that is never stored in the DB) for which the lifespan is the whole user (HTTP) session (can last a whole day or more) and **which is specific to each session/user** (here a "user" is a screen).

How to (cleanly) combine both states in order to maintain the transient state in-memory (in the HTTP session), while regularly refreshing the persistent state from the DB ? Use the same class and do Hibernate session.refresh() when needed ? Store both states in different classes and link them e.g. with the ID ? Decorator pattern ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand. If the object is read-only, what kind of information is transient? If the object is read-only, it will always be the same among all sessions. Maybe you mean that the object is not read-only, but it won't be persisted back to the server?

Comment: Some of the fields are persistent, and read-only in this part of the app. Some others are not persistent (so transient) but represent a (constantly changing) state that spans a user's session and is different for each session. I hope it's clearer so !

Comment: If the "transient" fields are not persistent, but are specific to a session, then you should consider using Stateful Session Beans (EJB). This way, the server takes care of delivering the specific SFSB to the client, and they can be cleared when the session expires (or is closed). The only "gotcha" here is that it seems you have these two informations in the same instance. I would argue that this is not ideal, as you are probably mixing concerns. But I cannot say that without knowing specifics of your problem.

Comment: Thanks! But i'm not switching to EJB now :) My solution for now : Store the Hibernate POJO in the HTTP session. This maintains the "transient" state across the user's session. Then I'll call hibernate's session.refresh when I need to re-read the persistent state. As I use a different hibernate session for each HTTP request, I can have several instances of the same persistent object, since a persistent object is only unique in the hibernate session scope. I'll upvote your answer but I can't really accept itm sorry...